# Setting value to hidden inputs on react hook forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a dynamic form created using `react-hook-form` and the `useFieldArray` hook. Its a form to create quotations where the user can add as many rows as he may needs.

On each line the user has to inform:

- Product name.
- Material.
- Units.

For now I have implemented the logic to add new rows and "sort of" show the price line. The unit price will come from our api but for now it's just the number of units multiplied by 10.

My issue comes to store the price line. I can show it but I don't know how to stored somewhere so I can submit it with the rest of the form and use it to show the total price.

This is the function I've perpared to show the price line value:

```
const priceLine = (control, index) => {
    const value = watch({ control, name: `rows.${index}` });

    // setValue(`value.rows[${index}]`, { priceLine: 20 });

    return value.rows[index].units * 10 || 0;
  };
```

If I use the `setValue` function my app crashes to prevent infinite re-render looping.

Those are the `useForm` and use `useFieldArray` hooks:

```
  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    setValue,
    reset,
    trigger,
    setError,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValue: { priceLine: 0 },
  });

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "rows",
  });
```

And this is the loop to show all the form fields on screen:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className={classes.new}>
              <div className={classes.new__row}>
                <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                  <label>Producto</label>
                  <input {...register(`rows.${index}.product`)} />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                  <label>Material</label>
                  <input {...register(`rows.${index}.material`)} />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                  <label>Units</label>
                  <input type="number" {...register(`rows.${index}.units`)} />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.new__row__field}>
                  <label>Total</label>
                  {/* <input
                    type="number"
                    disabled
                    value={priceLine(control, index)}

                  /> */}
                  <span>{priceLine(control, index)}</span>
                  <input
                    type="hidden"
                    {...register(`rows.${index}.priceLine`)}
                    defaultValue={item.priceLine}
                  />
                  {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                    x
                  </button> */}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.new__separator}></div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {/* <TotalQuotation base={base(control)} /> */}
        <div className={classes.new__buttons}>
          <Link to="/quotes" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} /> Volver al listado
          </Link>
          <button type="submit">Guardar presupuesto</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

When I submit the form I `console.log` it and this is the result:

```
{ ​​
material: "asdasdas",
priceLine: "",
product: "adadas",
units: "25"
}
```

It's the `react-hook-form` 7.22.

I only want to add some extra information to the object I'm getting when submitting the form, so maybe `setValue` it's not the appropriate function?

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem in your code at this line:

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  {...register(`rows.${index}.priceLine`)}
  defaultValue={item.priceLine}
/>
```

you can resolve it by including the default value within the register function like this:

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  {...register(`rows.${index}.priceLine`, { value: item.priceLine })}
  defaultValue={item.priceLine}
/>
```

This modification should resolve the issue and ensure that the default value item.priceLine is properly registered and rendered in the hidden input field.

This approach worked well for me, and I would recommend giving it a try.

Let me know if you have any questions or if this solution works for you!